# Audio problem Ubuntu 18.04 - HDA Intel PCH

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, intel

A while back (after I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04) the sound on my laptop (Dell XPS 13 9350) stopped working. Today I decided to fix it and followed the instructions here: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1833161.

I upgraded to the Kernel 5.0.2, as it was mentioned, and added the lines

```
options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=0x1
options snd-hda-intel model=clevo-p950
```

to the file 
/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

and everything seemed to be working. However, upon restarting the computer, nothing works again, even tho the file is still untouched.

After further experimentation, I found out the only line responsible for the fix was

```
options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=0x1
```

but as I said earlier, it only works after adding it to the original config file, and restarting once. If I restart twice, it will stop working and I will return to no sound.
What can I do to fix this?

Also, in the link mentioned above, it said to upgrade to the kernel 5.0.2 only to be able to make use of the second line in the config file.
However, I now do not need it, should I restore and go back to the original kernel, or is there no harm in staying in the upgraded kernel?

Thanks in advance